# AD users disabled through GUI shown as enabled in Powershell

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell

I tried to use Powershell to audit disabled AD user accounts but the results I get do not match what is shown in GUI through `Active Directory Users and Computers`.

DC is `Windows server 2012R2` and Powershell version `4.0`.

This lists only few of the users that are marked as disabled in GUI:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $false' |Select-Object -Property Samaccountname
```

This lists the same users as previous command:

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled |Select-Object |FT SamaccountName,ObjectClass
```

This lists many users that are marked as disabled in GUI:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' |Select-Object -Property Samaccountname
```

The user accounts have been disabled in following way:
In `Directory Users and Computers` right clicking the user object and selecting `Disable account`.

Powershell commands where issued on same DC where the accounts where disabled using GUI. There has been several days between accounts gettings disabled and the Powershell commands getting issued.

Is there issue with Powershell commmands I am using or does `disabled` mean different things is GUI and Powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your search queries are correct, and they should return all (and only) the user accounts that are actually disabled; if I'd have to guess, I'd point at replication issues between your domain controllers.

Plase note that *running ADUC or PowerShell on a DC is not the same as actually performing LDAP queries against that DC*; the ADUC console can bind to any DC (you can manually retarget it by right-clicking on the top level node in the left pane) and PowerShell can do the same (you can manually specify which DC to use with the `-Server` parameter). This is especially true if the DC you are logged on is not working correctly, in which case all AD administration tools can and will connect to another one.

Comment: With the help of `-Server` parameter I was able to find one DC that was not responsive. The other DCs gave list that matched what was shown in GUI.